# How to remove content padding before helper text in text form field flutter

Tags: flutter

I use contentPadding but message validate error align not at edge
How i can fix show message validate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using decorator inside TextFormField gives you access for content Padding.

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
              12, contentPaddingTop ?? 12, 0, contentPaddingBottom ?? 12))
```